# Someone please explain me the working of this code in a HTML program

Tags: html, css

Its a piece of code from HTML. The problem is I cant figure out what is the use and working of this lines.

```
<head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one,`http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css` styles code that is linked from `http://s3.amazonaws.com`

The second one, `main.css` that is linked from your local folder, it contains your own customized styles.

Both files for styles of your page.

You have to learn more about css [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in Thank you!
Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It links two CSS stylesheets into your HTML document.

The first one is remote, placed and linked from server `s3.amazinaws.com`.
The second one is local, it's put in to same directory as HTML document.

Ex.:
If your HTML document is in domain root, `main.css` is in root too.
If your HTML document is eg. `/contact/career.php`, CSS file has to be in `/contact/` dir too.

More info eg. here, http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import

Answer (score 0):

For applying CSS rules onto your HTML-elements, the main.css overwrites and/or extends existing rules in shift.css, loaded from s3.amazonaws.com.

e.g.:

If you have a DOM structure like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
```

and `shift.css` contains the rule:

```
.list li {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
}
```

and `main.css` contains the rule:

```
.list li {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

this will be the "resulting" rule:

```
.list li {
  background-color: green; /* main css override shift.css */
  color: yellow; /* from shift.css */
  font-weight: bold;  /* extendion of the rule made by from main.css */
}
```

Comment: I doubt that anyone who doesn't know what those lines mean would know what a DOM is:)

Answer (score 0):

They are both stylesheets for your web page.
When a browser reads a style sheet, it will format the web page according to the rules set out on the style sheet.

You see how the both end in `.css` this stands for *Cascading Style Sheet*.

**Stylesheet Set by Codecademy:**

> http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css

**Stylesheet specific to website:**

> "main.css"

Ensure that `main.css` is in the same folder as index.html, or if not, change the file path to whatever folder `main.css` is in. For example: `"css/main.css"`.

There are three ways of inserting a stylesheet

- External style sheet
- Internal style sheet
- Inline style sheet

The two style sheets you have linked are *external* as they are not held directly within the html file.

When linking to an external style sheet `href=""` tells the browser where the style sheet is stored, and `rel=""` tells the browser the relationship between the current document and linked one; in this case, stylesheet.

If you are fairly new to web development, you may be used to using *inline style*.

***Example of Inline Style:***

```
<h1 style="color:red;margin-left:10px;">This is using inline style.</h1>
```